# How can I tell if the search string returned from SearchManager is a result of a VoiceSearch?

Tags: android

In my searchable.xml, I have:

```
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
```

I get the search string returned SearchManager like so:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(action)) {
  searchString = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
}
```

Is there any way to get from the intent whether the search string came from the keyboard, or as a result of voice search and the speech Recognizer?

I know I can put entities like:

> ```
> <actionkey android:keycode="KEYCODE_SEARCH" android:queryActionMsg="search"/>
> <actionkey android:keycode="KEYCODE_ENTER" android:queryActionMsg="enter"/>
> ```

in my searchable.xml file, and then use intent.getIntExtra(SearchManager.ACTION_KEY,-999) to see if the search started because the user hit the **Enter** key on the keyboard, or the hardware **Search** button, but I don't see how to detect that the search was started from the "microphone" icon button, or the "search" icon button in the search bar.

(In the case of a voice search, I need to echo the text back to the user while I do a further web lookup. For a text search, echoing what the user just typed is redundant.)

How can I tell the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: if I just type a query, the QUERY and the USER_QUERY both return the typed text. If I speak it, the USER_QUERY is null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the voice input is just an input method editor (IME), and you aren't going to be able to get any info on what IME was used to enter the text.

Comment: No, it's not an input method.

Comment: Voice input is not an IME?  Where do you see that information?

Comment: Quoting from: 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html

"If [launchRecognizer is] set, the voice search button will take the user directly to a built-in voice recording activity. This activity will prompt the user to speak, transcribe the spoken text, and forward the resulting query text to the searchable activity, just as if the user had typed it into the search UI and clicked the search button."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html says "An input method (IME) is implemented as a Service..."

Comment: Since one is an Activity, and the other is a a Service, I assumed they were different things.